# converting 1-D list into a 2-D list in Python

Tags: python

Assuming I have a the a list of 9 items, 
I want to convert it into a list of 3 by 3 items

from [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] -> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

this is the code:

```
def main():

    L = range(1,10)
    twoD= [[0]*3]*3     #creates [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

    c = 0
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            twoD[i][j] = L[c]

            c+=1
```

for some reason this returns

```
twoD = [[7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
```

and I have no clue why, what is making it do this?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Comment: Reason: [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists)

Comment: Oh wow, never thought about that! thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following list comprehension.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

More generally, you could write such a function

```
def reshape(l, d):
    return [l[i:i+d] for i in range(0, len(l), d)]


>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

>>> reshape(l,3)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]

>>> reshape(l,5)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: this is a great technique, but I want to understand why mine is returning the wrong value?

Comment: Because the way you are generating the inner lists is making copies of the same sublist. See the above linked posts in the comments.